# Pandas: Retrieving nested data from JSON File

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am parsing nested JSON data from [here](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/hr.zip). Some of the files within this file have more than one `committee_id` associated with them. I need all of the committees associated with each file. I'm not sure, but I imagine that would mean writing a new row for each `committee_id`. My code follows:

```
import os.path
import csv
import json

path = '/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/Thesis/govtrack/bills109/hr'
dirs = os.listdir(path)
outputfile = open('df/h109_s_b', 'w', newline='')                            
outputwriter = csv.writer(outputfile)

for dir in dirs:
    with open(path + "/" + dir + "/data.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        a = data['introduced_at']
        b = data['bill_id']
        c = data['sponsor']['thomas_id']
        d = data['sponsor']['state']
        e = data['sponsor']['name']
        f = data['sponsor']['type']
        i = data['subjects_top_term']   
        j = data['official_title']               

        if data['committees']:
            g = data['committees'][0]['committee_id']
        else:
            g = "None"                      
    outputwriter.writerow([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, i, j])
outputfile.close()
```

The problem I am having is that my code is only collecting the first `committee_id` listed. For example, file `hr145` looks like this:

```
 "committees": [
{
  "activity": [
    "referral", 
    "in committee"
  ], 
  "committee": "House Transportation and Infrastructure", 
  "committee_id": "HSPW"
}, 
{
  "activity": [
    "referral"
  ], 
  "committee": "House Transportation and Infrastructure", 
  "committee_id": "HSPW", 
  "subcommittee": "Subcommittee on Economic Development, Public Buildings and Emergency Management", 
  "subcommittee_id": "13"
}, 
{
  "activity": [
    "referral", 
    "in committee"
  ], 
  "committee": "House Financial Services", 
  "committee_id": "HSBA"
}, 
{
  "activity": [
    "referral"
  ], 
  "committee": "House Financial Services", 


  "committee_id": "HSBA", 
  "subcommittee": "Subcommittee on Domestic and International Monetary Policy, Trade, and Technology", 
  "subcommittee_id": "19"
}
```

This is where it is a little bit tricky because I also want the `subcommittee_id` associated with the `committee_id` when the bill gets passed to a subcommittee:

```
bill_iid    committee   subcommittee    introduced at   Thomas_id   state   name
hr145-109   HSPW          na             "2005-01-4"         73      NY "McHugh, John M."
hr145-109   HSPW          13             "2005-01-4"         73      NY "McHugh, John M."
hr145-109   HSBA          na             "2005-01-4"         73      NY "McHugh, John M."
hr145-109   HSBA          19             "2005-01-4"         73      NY "McHugh, John M."
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [111]: with open(fn) as f:
   .....:     data = ujson.load(f)
   .....:

In [112]: committees = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, 'committees')

In [113]: committees
Out[113]:
             activity                                committee committee_id                            subcommittee subcommittee_id
0          [referral]                House Energy and Commerce         HSIF                                     NaN             NaN
1          [referral]                House Energy and Commerce         HSIF  Subcommittee on Energy and Air Quality              03
2          [referral]        House Education and the Workforce         HSED                                     NaN             NaN
3          [referral]                 House Financial Services         HSBA                                     NaN             NaN
4          [referral]                        House Agriculture         HSAG                                     NaN             NaN
5  [referral, markup]                          House Resources         HSII                                     NaN             NaN
6          [referral]                            House Science         HSSY                                     NaN             NaN
7          [referral]                     House Ways and Means         HSWM                                     NaN             NaN
8          [referral]  House Transportation and Infrastructure         HSPW                                     NaN             NaN
```

**UPDATE:**

if you want to have all your data in one DF you can do it this way:

```
import os
import ujson
import pandas as pd

start_path = '/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/Thesis/govtrack/bills109/hr'

def get_merged_json(start_path):
    return [ujson.load(open(os.path.join(path, f)))
            for p, _, files in os.walk(start_path)
            for f in files
            if f.endswith('.json')
           ]

df = pd.read_json(ujson.dumps(data))
```

PS it will put all `committees` in one column as JSON data though

Comment: Thanks again MaxU! I have a small question: what should `fn`be pointing to? Wait, I think I got it. `fn`= `filename`.

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, yes, it should be full or relative path to your file including its name

Comment: I have applied your code with one exception. I have substituted json for ujson, as I was getting a `NameError: name 'ujson' is not defined
`.  However, it is only returning one row. As fn I am using `(path + "/" + dir + "/data.json", "r")` I can probably tool around with it to get it working, but would you have an idea of what that is?

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, the number of rows will vary depending of number of elements in the `committees` list in each file

Comment: I need to go through each of the 6436 files within the file that I am working with (the one that has a link to it). I thought that by using `for dir in dirs:
    with open(path + "/" + dir + "/data.json", "r") as f:` It would do that automatically.

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, i've updated my answer - please check. I would also open a new question about how to expand a JSON column into multiple columns, because it might be tricky